# Why connecting lines are disappearing once I push the content inside tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a framework jquery-connections to connect elements on the web page. Problem is whenever I am pushing the content inside the Tab connectors are disappearing.

[image]

When I include

```
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Content goes inside the Tab but Connecting lines are missing
[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("discovery")

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="decorator" content="atl.general">
    <title>Jquery Discovery</title>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('h1 *').connections({ to: 'div:first', 'class': 'first' });
            $('div.styles .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.styles li:nth-child(1)', within: '.styles', tag: 'inner', css: { zIndex: -1 } });
            $('div.styles .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.styles li:nth-child(2)', within: '.styles', tag: 'inner', css: { color: '#d62' } });
            $('div.styles .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.styles li:nth-child(3)', within: '.styles', tag: 'inner', css: { borderWidth: 0.5 } });
            $('div.styles .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.styles li:nth-child(4)', within: '.styles', tag: 'inner', css: { borderRadius: 0 } });
            $('div.styles .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.styles li:nth-child(5)', within: '.styles', tag: 'inner', css: { borderStyle: 'double' } });
            $('div.positioning .anchor').connections({ to: 'div.positioning li', tag: 'inner' });
            $('div.new-div, div.styles').connections();
            $('p.styles, p.positioning').connections();
            $('connection:odd').addClass('odd');
            var connections = $('connection, inner');
            setInterval(function() { connections.connections('update') }, 100);
        });
    </script>

    <style>

        .aui-navgroup-horizontal .aui-nav > .aui-nav-selected a:before,
        .aui-navgroup-horizontal .aui-nav > .aui-nav-selected a:after {
            position: fixed;
        }


        p, div.styles, div.new-div ,  div.positioning, div.more{
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            float: left;
            min-width: 4em;
            min-height: 3em;
            max-width: 29ex;
            margin: 3em;
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 16px;
            box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }
        pre {
            font: 0.9em monospace;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #ddd;
            color: #555;
        }

        connection {
            z-index: -1;
            border: 3px solid;
            border-radius: 7em;
            color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        connection.odd {
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        connection.first {
            color: black;
            border: 5px dotted;
        }
        inner {
            border: 4px solid;
            border-radius: 16px;
            color: #668;
        }
        .anchor {
            display: block;
            width: 0;
            margin-top: 0.1em;
            margin-left: 1em;
        }
        .more {
            float: right;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="aui-tabs horizontal-tabs" role="application">
    <ul class="tabs-menu" role="tablist">
        <li class="menu-item active-tab" role="presentation">
            <a href="#tabs-example-first" id="aui-uid-0-1436371221001" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><strong>Tab 1</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" role="presentation">
            <a href="#tabs-example-second" id="aui-uid-1-1436371221001" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><strong>Tab 2</strong></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-pane active-pane" id="tabs-example-first" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
        <h2>This is Tab 1</h2>

        #*<p class="new-div">
            Adds lines between page elements using CSS borders.
        </p>*#

        <div class='styles'>
            Connections are separate elements that can be styled individually. Examples:
        </div>

        <br />
        <p class='positioning'>
            Dynamic repositioning is optional. Update strategies are not constrained by the plugin. Ideas:

        </p>

            <div class="new-div">
                Connections are separate elements that can be styled individually. Examples:
            #*<span id="myspan">For <b>$endUsers</b> who<b>$problemsArea <b> is a <b>$productKind</b> that <b>$problemSoln</b> unlike </b>$differntitaor</b> our product <b>$prod</b> </span>*#
            </div>


        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="tabs-pane" id="tabs-example-second" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
        <h2>This is Tab 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a CSS `z-index` issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Hi Rory, thanks. After I removed the z-index lines have started appearing but if I remove the z-index won't it will change the stack order of the elements?

Comment: Yes it will, but if it works then it's not a problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: For now I am alright , may be in future I may have to worry :)..........can you put your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks - answer added for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  It would be great if could explain me how z-index is responsible for this.

Comment: You need to think of each element of an HTML document as a layer. The `z-index` is the property that sets the level of that layer. For example, something with `z-index: 5` will appear *below* something with a `z-index: 6`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a CSS `z-index` issue. You need to either move the connections above the tabs, or tabs below the connections. something like this:

```
.tab {
    z-index: 5;
}
.connection { 
    z-index: 10;
}
```